# $.post is not working in asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, jquery-ui

I have following code in page index.aspx but it is not working.

I want to submit name and email to webmethod using Jquery. Code is working till it reach to `$.post` but after that it is not working.   Please help

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var name = $("#name").val();
    if (email != '') {
        if (validateEmail(email)) {
            $.post('index.aspx/SubscriberSubmit', { name: name, email: email }, function (data) {
                var newDiv = $(document.createElement('div'));
                newDiv.html(data);
                newDiv.dialog({ minHeight: 100, modal: true });
                $("#email").val('Please Enter Your Email ID');
                $("#name").val('Please Enter Your Name');
            });
        }
        else {
            var newDiv = $(document.createElement('div'));
            newDiv.html('Please Enter a Valid Email ID');
            newDiv.dialog({ minHeight: 100, modal: true });
            $("#email").val('');
        }
    }
});
```

webmethod is in codebehind

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SubscriberSubmit(string name, string email)
{
    return "hello";
}
```

Please suggest where i am wrong

Comment: Have you check wheter request is sent in browser's tools?

Comment: What error happens? Are there any exceptions? its hard to guess without errors data

Comment: Try to put it inside Document.Ready() { }

Comment: Sorry i am new in jquery. how to check request is sent in browser

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```
<input id="submit" type="submit"/>
```

or

```
<button id="submit"></button>
```

on click after sending post request, processed submit and page reload, so just change your markup like

```
<input id="submit" type="button"/>
<button id="submit" type="button"></button>
```